# How can I save Edge read aloud file for offline usage?

Tags: microsoft-edge, text-to-speech, tts

Edge browser has this read aloud feature, It reads text from any web page you want with a natural voice (there are robotic voice options too)

but this feature doesn't work offline. Is there any ways (plugins, website, etc...) that let me save the audio file for offline usage (like an export button to get an mp3 file)?

I know it's possible to record the audio with tools like Audacity but it can take a long time, and I'm working with my computer, I can't let it record audio all the time.

ps: there are some online alternatives but the free ones are low quality or have very limited characters like 500